# anyone know how i remove this border of react-syntax-highlighter?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, syntax-highlighting, react-syntax-highlighter

i have this structure and need remove the borders/lines that are rendered

```js
<ReactMarkdown
          className="w-100"
          children={text}
          remarkPlugins={[gfm]}
          components={{
            code({ className, children, style, ...props }) {
              const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || "");
              return (
                <SyntaxHighlighter
                  children={String(children)}
                  showLineNumbers
                  lineProps={}
                  style={currentTheme === "dark" ? dracula : vs}
                  language={match![1]}
                  {...props}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkaeA.png)

i using the props syntaxhighlighter to try change something, but did not work